# How do I find the limit of $n(e^{-n} - 1)$ as n approaches infinity?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I have tried all the common things, such as dividing by n or trying to transform it into something that would give me $(1+ \frac{1}{n})^n$, but I can't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

As $n$ goes to $\infty$, $e^{-n}$ goes to $0$, so $e^{-n}-1$ goes to $-1$. If a sequence $a_n$ does not go to $0$, what do we know about the sequence $na_n$?

Comment: I would add that we know $a_n$ converges.

Comment: Why can we take one infinity before the other? Couldn't we in the same way conclude that (1+(1/n))^n goes to infinity, or even zero, as well? I would appreciate it a lot if there is a more formal and clearer way to show that this sequence actually goes to infinity. Thank you

Comment: @Matthew There is no "other infinity". $n$ diverges while $e^{-n}-1$ converges to $-1$. You'd have a problem if that convergence was to $0$, but it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Expand and you get lim n->infinity n/e^n - n. This clearly goes to negative infinity because  n/e^n -> 0 and -n->-infinity

Answer (score 0):

$e^{-n}<1/2$ for $n \ge 1$.

$n(e^{-n}-1) <n((1/2)-1)=$

$n(-1/2)=-(n/2)$.